# ¿Cómo consequir el texto visible de un select usando selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Me gustaria conseguir el texto visible de un select usando selenium para meterlos en una lista de strings.

```
<select id="selector">
 <option value="0">Texto0</option>
 <option value="1">Texto2</option>
 <option value="2">Texto2</option>
 <option value="3">Texto3</option>
</select>
```

Por el moento solo he conseguido obtener los valores de "value" con esta función.

```
def seleciona_marca(driver):
 selector = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("selector"))
 for element in selector.options:
  print( element.get_attribute("value") )
```

La salida de esta funcion es

```
0    
1    
2    
3
```

Y yo quiero hacer una parecida que tenga esta salida:

```
Texto0
Texto1
Texto2
Texto3
```

He estado leyendo la documentación de Selenium referente a los Selects pero no dice como poder hacer esto:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: prueba con `element.get_attribute('innerHTML')`

Comment: OK, Funciona!! Muchas Gracias @aloMalbarez

Answer (score 0):

Para cualquier select, como opcion generica, puedes hacer algo asi:

```
Select mySelect = new Select(drivers.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)));
mySelect.getFirstSelectedOption().getText().toString();
```

Una vez creado el objeto select, si ese select es multivalor, puedes obtener todos los valores seleccionados con:

```
mySelect.getAllSelectedOptions();
```

Comment: Si, asi es, pero yo lo que queria saber era como conseguir el texto de cada opción... la resouesta de Alo Malbarez me sirvió... era así ***element.get_attribute('innerHTML')***... Pero gracias de todos modos por contestar. Un Saludo!!

Comment: Y que tal la opcion `mySelect.getOptions();`

Comment: Si, de ahí sale... mira mi pregunta ahí arriba es lo mismo que esto ( selector.options)